# Why am I not getting WM_UPDATEUISTATE?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a main window with an edit control and a custom button. When the edit control has focus and I press the Tab key, the button control gets the focus but it never receives `WM_UPDATEUISTATE`? I'm using `IsDialogMessage()` in the message loop of main window. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Edit: Why isn't the custom button control receiving `WM_UPDATEUISTATE`?

Edit: `IsDialogMessage()` is not sending `WM_UPDATEUISTATE` or `WM_CHANGUISTATE` in this example

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

HINSTANCE g_hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{ 
    static HWND hBtn1, hBtn2;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hBtn1 = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Button 1"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            4, 4, 100, 40, hwnd, 0, g_hInst, 0);
        if(!hBtn1) return -1;

        hBtn2 = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Button 2"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            114, 4, 100, 40, hwnd, 0, g_hInst, 0);
        if(!hBtn1) return -1;
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break; 

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}


int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{ 
    const TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("Main////");
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    SecureZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return 0;

    g_hInst = hInstance;
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, szClassName, TEXT("Main"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 140, 140, 440, 240, 0, 0, hInstance, 0); 
    if(!hwnd) return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        if(!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

I've used spy++ for the main window and the 2 buttons when pressing the Tab key and I don't see neither `WM_UPDATEUISTATE` nor `WM_CHANGEUISTATE` anywhere, but the standard button control draws the focus rect. How does the standard button know when to draw the focus rect?

[image]

Comment: Are you passing [WM_CHANGEUISTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646342.aspx) messages to the default window procedure, so that it can propagate to the parent window, which in turn sends `WM_UPDATEUISTATE` to its child windows.

Comment: If you mean when the button receives focus, then no I'm not. But how do I know if the button received focus because the Tab key was pressed?

Comment: Yes the default window procedure is processing `WM_CHANGEUISTATE`

Comment: I've heard `IsDialogMessage()` sends `WM_UPDATEUISTATE` but it is not. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the main window is not a dialog box

Comment: Is the button control supposed to check if the Tab key was pressed and then send `WM_CHANGEUISTATE` to parent?

Comment: `IsDialogMessage()` sends `WM_CHANGEUISTATE`, which needs to be passed on to the default window procedure. The default window procedure propagates the message to its parent, until it finds a window that has no parent. The default window procedure of that window then converts this message to a `WM_UPDATEUISTATE` message, that's passed to all child windows. You can call `IsDialogMessage()` for any window, not just dialogs.

Comment: A [mcve] would probably help.

Comment: The button control draws the focus rectangle because the `UISF_HIDEFOCUS` flag is clear. (It's clear because that's the default, and you did nothing to set it.) Pressing the tab key clears the flag, but since the flag is already clear, there is nothing to change.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. After some thinking I've come to the conclusion that my custom button control must check if the virtual key in `WM_KEYDOWN` is `VK_TAB` and if so send a `WM_CHANGEUISTATE` message to the parent window. Since I return `DLGC_BUTTON | DLGC_UNDEFPUSHBUTTON` from `WM_GETDLGCODE` I don't receive `WM_KEYDOWN` when virtual key is `VK_TAB` so I'm thinking of checking for the Tab key in `WM_GETDLGCODE` or `'WM_KEYUP`. Is my conclusion correct and if so what is the best message to check in if the Tab key is down?

Answer (score 2):

A window should show its focus indicator when it has focus.  For that, a control should watch for [WM_SETFOCUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-setfocus) and [WM_KILLFOCUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-killfocus).  When it has the focus, a well-behaved control will check the UI state by sending [WM_QUERYUISTATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-queryuistate) to itself, and, if the UI state has the UISF_HIDEFOCUS flag set, the control would not draw the focus indicator.

The [WM_CHANGEUISTATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-changeuistate) and [WM_UPDATEUISTATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-updateuistate) are responsible for controlling whether a tree of windows (including controls) should display keyboard "cues" and focus indicators *in general*.  For example, if the cues aren't showing and you tap the ALT key, these messages will update the UI state of the windows in the tree so that they start showing the cues.  These messages are not used for hiding the focus indicator from one control and showing it on the next as the user TABs through the controls.  That effect happens because the controls pay attention to the focus change messages.

Generally speaking, a custom control should watch for the focus change messages and let DefWindowProc handle the UI state messages.

Raymond Chen has a series of blog posts about the UI state and how these messages propagate.

- [Untangling the confusingly-named WM_UPDATEUISTATE and WM_CHANGEUISTATE messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130516-00/?p=4343)
- [Who sends the initial WM_UPDATEUISTATE message?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130517-00/?p=4323)
- [Why does tapping the Alt key cause my owner-draw static control to repaint?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161212-00/?p=94915)
- [What is the documentation for SetParent trying to tell me about synchronizing the UI state?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171122-00/?p=97445)
- [Demonstrating what happens when a parent and child window have different UI states](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171123-00/?p=97455)
- [Getting a parent and child window to have the same UI states](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171124-00/?p=97456)

I found these helpful when I recently tried to work all this out again.  The current state of the official documentation on this topic is a bit vague and ambiguous in places.

Note:  The terms "mnemonics," "accelerators," and "hot keys" have blurred together, even in the official Microsoft documentation and some of the API names.  When I say "keyboard cues," I'm mostly referring to mnemonics (sometimes called "shortcuts" or "access keys").  Those are the underlined characters in control labels and menu items that let the user know that `ALT+<character>` will select the labeled item.